# Error RCTImageView

Tags: json, image, react-native

i found error in react native. if i need show my image from json what must i do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrYd2.jpg)

```js
<View>
  <Image style={styles.logo} source={{uri : rowData.produk_gambar}}  />   
</View>
```

what wrong guys? this is my code for image

[my json respone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3JD.png)

Comment: Well i meant this code should work im curious to see what is inside of the  rowData.produk_gambar  var

Comment: it must be that the stuff inside of rowdata.pro... is blank or undefined. Can you verify that what you think is in there is in there

Comment: Yes I think that picture was there but I don't know how to call him. Because I just learned how to use react a native sir

Comment: You need to assign url of image in source object not array. as per you json you are assigning array. it should like source={{url: rowData.produk_gambar[0]['url']}}

Comment: See this doc http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#source-as-an-object

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like below.

```
<View>
  <Image style={styles.logo} source={{uri : rowData.produk_gambar.length > 0 ? rowData.produk_gambar[0]['url'] : null }}  />
```

and URL should be network url.

Comment: cant sir, we have new error "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"

Comment: You need to add one condition for produk_gambar is empty or not.

Comment: ur code work but, idont see the picture. im sorry i dont understand

Comment: in your response, you are getting sometimes empty data. may be, because of you have not uploaded images for those product yet.

Comment: hmm can u give example sir?